# Populate span tag with data from a json file

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

On [THIS](http://dev.magazinuldecase.ro/imobiliarebuc/) page, I have listed some dummy estates and hard-coded, for each one, a span (with the text "VEZI TELEFON") that when clicked, reveals a phone number. I want every phone number to be retrieved from a JSON (or PHP) file called *telefoane.json* that has the content:

```
 {
  "telefoane":[{
  "id":"1",
  "tel":"0743127315"
 },
 {
  "id":"2",
  "tel":"072245875"
 },
 {
  "id":"3",
  "tel":"0756129458"
 },
 {
  "id":"4",
  "tel":"0725127216"
 },
 {
  "id":"5",
  "tel":"0723127322"
 }]
}
```

My code, that can be seen below does not output the desired result:

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'telefoane.json',
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data){
   $.each(data, function(key, val){
    console.log(key + ":" + val);
  });
 }
});
```

The output is, unfortunately:

```
telefoane:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

EDIT:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'telefoane.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(){
        $.each(data.telefoane, function() {
            console.log(this.id + ": " + this.tel);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop will give you the objects of `data.telefoane`. So you need to access the content by the property names.

```js
var data = {
  "telefoane": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "tel": "0743127315"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "tel": "072245875"
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "tel": "0756129458"
  }]
};

$.each(data.telefoane, function(i, object) {
  console.log(object.id + ": " + object.tel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or use `this`:

```js
var data = {
  "telefoane": [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "tel": "0743127315"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "tel": "072245875"
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "tel": "0756129458"
  }]
};

$.each(data.telefoane, function() {
  console.log(this.id + ": " + this.tel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have used your code (witch obsequiously works) inside mine (after success) and the console does not output anything...

Comment: Please show me your code (*maybe as edit in your question*). @user1647234

Comment: You need to add `data` as parameter of your `success` function. `success: function(data) { ...` @user1647234

Comment: I just did it but I can't see any changes. Can you?

Comment: I don't understnd your question. What can I? @user1647234